# How do I return the address of a node?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to return the address of a node after I find it.

The node object class is inside a tree class set as private (private is the node inside)

I'll show you a function that's very similar to what I want but with a bool return type.
It returns true if the node exists within the tree or false if it's not there, I only want to return the pointer or address of the node containing the element Im looking for, so I can  work with it in the future.

below is the Function. (the "t" im passing is an integer)

```
template <class T>
class Arbol
{
    private:
    template <class DNodo>
    class Nodo
    {
        public:
            Nodo(const DNodo  datoPasado,
                 Nodo<DNodo> *izqPasado=NULL,//HIJO IZQUIERDO NULL
                 Nodo<DNodo> *derPasado=NULL)//HIJO DERECHO NULL
                  : dato(datoPasado),izq(izqPasado),der(derPasado){}
                  Nodo();
            //members
            DNodo         dato;
            Nodo<DNodo>  *izq;
            Nodo<DNodo> *der;
    };

   Nodo<T> *raiz;//variable raiz de la clase interna
   Nodo<T> *actual;//posicion actual
   int contador;//contador
   int altura;//altura
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////
   public:
   Arbol() : raiz(NULL), actual(NULL){};
   //Iniciar(const T &t);
   ~Arbol();
   //INSERTO EN EL ARBOL
   void Insertar(const T t);
   //BORRO ELEMENTO DEL ARBOL
   void Borrar(const T t);
   //Busca un elemento del arbol
   bool Buscar(const T t);
   //Busca y devuelve puntero a elemento
   Nodo<T>* BuscarDevolver(const T t);
   //EsVacio ????
   bool EsVacio();

   };



  template<class T>
  Node<T>* Arbol<T>::BuscarDevolver(const T t)
  {
    if(!EsVacio())
    {
      actual = raiz;
      while(actual!=NULL)
         if(actual->dato == t)
            return actual;
        else if(t < actual->dato)
            {
                actual = actual->izq;
            }
        else if(t > actual->dato)
        {
            actual = actual->der;
        }

    }
    return NULL;
}
```

As you may noticed it Im searching for a node in an Binary tree
Thanks in advance for trying to help.

Im getting errors like "Node does not name a type"

Comment: The error you get is not triggered by the code you posted, post the actual code.

Comment: the error I get occurs when I set the return type:

template<class T>
Node<T>* Arbol<T>::Buscar(const T t)

Comment: Well edit the code to reflect that. Also show the definition of `Node`, isn't a nested type within `Arbol` by the way?

Comment: maybe i just can't do what I want and the answer is to make the modification when I find the node, and not returning anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Node` is a nested type within `Arbol`, so you should actually declare your function like this:

```
template< class T > Arbol<T>::Node<T>* Arbol<T>::Buscar(const T t);
```

Comment: the solution consists in changing the code to:
in the declaration:
      Nodo<T>* Arbol<T>::BuscarDevolver(const T t){.......}

      and the function return type to
      template<class T>
      Arbol<T>::Nodo<T>*